# Common header/title for all slides in power point 2007

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint-2007

I would like to create a common header/title for all the slides in my presentation so that if i decide to make a change at a later point to the title/hearder of the slider i do not need to go to each slide and make it but will make it at one place and will be reflected in all of them. I have looked at the Insert-> Header/Footer and also the slide master but it does not appear when i bring up the slidshow mode.
Please let me know if oyu have any suggestions.
Thanks
N

Answer (score 1):

Headers/Footers are fairly badly broken in PPT 2007 and beyond.  There are ways of getting them to work but honestly, it's far simpler to do what you want this way:

Go to Slide Master view.

To the topmost master, add the header text you want to use.  Normally it'll appear on each of the layouts indented below the master, but in some cases, might not.  In that case, copy/paste it to each of the layouts where it's missing, but desired.

If there are multiple masters in your presentation, you might need to copy/paste the text there too.

The only hitch here is that content on individual slides can cover the text from the master.  In that case you'd need to decide.  If it's ok, then no worries. If not, either adjust the position/size of the content on the slide or copy/paste the text on top of the slide from the master.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a header and footer to one or more slides in your presentation. You have to just follow some steps.
Add a footer to all slides:

1. Click on the Insert menu. In text group select Header & Footer option.
2. In the Header & Footer dialog box, on the Slide tab select the Footer check box and type the text what you want to show.
3. Now if you don’t want footer text on your title slide then select the Don't show on title slide check box.[image]
4. If you want footer on the all of the slides in your presentation then click Apply to All, or to display footer information on the selected slide only then click Apply.

To add both header & footer to a handout or notes page, please follow the steps as below:

1. Click on the Insert menu. In text group select Header & Footer option.
2. In the Header & Footer dialog box, select the Notes and Handouts tab and check on the Header or Footer check box, then type the text that you want to appear in the header or footer of each notes page or handout.

[image]
3. Click on Apply to all.

Hope this helps you....

Comment: Thanks for your response and time. These are the steps i have exactly followed but i do not see the header after this. Inspite of these steps i am manually adding title to all my slides. Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Comment: I have noticed the header does not display when in slideshow but when i am editing it displays. Just wondering what i m missing. Thanks